# A peculiar question regarding marriage?

Tags: puranas, marriage, varna, itihasa, kings

Namaste,
Is there any mention in our scriptures about a man marrying a girl of different kingdom? Of course there are mentions about kings..but are there mentions about other varnas like Brahmanas or Vaishyas marrying girls from other kingdoms/regions?
Kindly answer..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. Sage Rishyasringa married Shanta, the princess of Anga -

> "On entering the palace princess Shanta is given to Rishyasringa in
> customary marriage, and then that King Romapada obtained rejoice with
> a peaceful mind."

Bala Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.